# How to add data to R data frame

Tags: r

I can't imagine it should be that difficult, but probably, coming from Python, my mindset is biased.

I know I'm going to carry out 50 calculations and the result of each calculation, together with two parameters characterizing the calculation, should build up a data frame.

So my approach is to instantiate the data frame and then I want to add the results whenever they become available. Please see the indicated row below:

```
# Number of simulations
nsim = 50

# The data frame which should carry the calculation (parameters and solutions).
sol <- data.frame(col.names=c("ni", "Xbar", "n"))

# Fifty values for n.
n <- seq.int(5, 5000, length.out=nsim)

for(ni in n)
{
    # A random sample containing possible duplicates.
    X <- sample(seq(-ni, ni, length=ni+1), replace=T)
    Xbar <- round(mean(X), 3)
    sol <- rbind(sol, c(ni, Xbar, n))  # <<-- How to do this correctly??
}
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this correctly. One is to pre-define your data.frame (its size) and then populate it iteratively in a for-loop:

```
nsim <- 10 # reduce to 10 to simplify output
n <- seq.int(5, 5000, length.out=nsim)

sol <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow=nsim, ncol=3)), c("ni", "Xbar", "n"))

set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
for(ni in seq_along(n)) {
    Xbar <- round(mean(sample(seq(-n[ni], n[ni], length=n[ni]+1), replace=T)), 3)
    sol[ni,] <- c(ni, Xbar, n[ni])
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `sapply` on your `n` vector to create a vector of results and then `cbind` everything back together:

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
sol <- data.frame(
    ni = seq_along(n),
    Xbar = sapply(n, function(ni) {
        round(mean(sample(seq(-ni, ni, length=ni+1), replace=T)), 3)
    }),
    n = n
)
```

Either way, you'll end up with a nice dataframe:

```
> str(sol)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ni  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Xbar: num  0.667 -0.232 -14.599 -26.026 36.51 ...
 $ n   : num  5 560 1115 1670 2225 ...
```

Comment: @thelatemail Correct. Fixed. Feel free to just edit that kind of stuff on my answers in the future. :)

Comment: Ok so I need to instantiate the data frame with its size from the start.

Comment: @TMOTTM You don't *have* to do it, but it is many times more efficient to initialize and fill rather than repeatedly `rbind` because the `rbind` will copy the data.frame in memory each time.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check what your initial `sol` contains.

```
> sol <- data.frame(col.names=c("ni", "Xbar", "n"))
> sol
  col.names
1        ni
2      Xbar
3         n
```

Not what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame).

2) Make sure `seq.int` does what you expect - check the documentation of (or just the output of) `seq.int`. e.g. look at what `n` contains:

```
> n
 [1]    5.0000  106.9388  208.8776  310.8163  412.7551  514.6939  616.6327
 [8]  718.5714  820.5102  922.4490 1024.3878 1126.3265 1228.2653 1330.2041
[15] 1432.1429 1534.0816 1636.0204 1737.9592 1839.8980 1941.8367 2043.7755
[22] 2145.7143 2247.6531 2349.5918 2451.5306 2553.4694 2655.4082 2757.3469
[29] 2859.2857 2961.2245 3063.1633 3165.1020 3267.0408 3368.9796 3470.9184
[36] 3572.8571 3674.7959 3776.7347 3878.6735 3980.6122 4082.5510 4184.4898
[43] 4286.4286 4388.3673 4490.3061 4592.2449 4694.1837 4796.1224 4898.0612
[50] 5000.0000
```

Is that what you meant?

3) Given (1) the problems are not surprising, but in any case, just carry out the first time through the loop a line at a time. See what happens:

```
sim = 50
sol <- data.frame(col.names=c("ni", "Xbar", "n"))
ni=5
X <- sample(seq(-ni, ni, length=ni+1), replace=T)
Xbar <- round(mean(X), 3)
sol <- rbind(sol, c(ni, Xbar, n))  
print(sol)
```

Gives:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 5) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
>     print(sol)
  col.names
1        ni
2      Xbar
3         n
4      <NA>
```

Now the behavior is unsurprising; we can't add three columns to something with one column.

4) You don't want to do it this way anyway. It's better to initialize `sol` to be its final size and then fill it in.

See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917695/330679)

However, the more common R idiom would be to avoid loops where possible; there are a number of functions that will let you create the whole thing at once.

Comment: 1-3) I get that. 4) The purpose of the question is exactly to learn how to do that "filling in". That's my main problem of understanding.

Comment: 3) I assume that by defining `col.names`, I'm defining the number of columns, am I not?

Comment: You're not. You're defining a variable called `col.names`, which is why you get one column, not 3. `data.frame` doesn't have a `col.names` argument. See `?data.frame`. I've added a link to my answer to clarify the issue in your first comment there.

Comment: You're right, misread the 'row.names' argument in `?data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you clarify the expected output format that you expect?
As of now, on modifying the code to generate a data frame, the following output will be generated (let me know if this is what you expect & then its not difficult to generate the following) :

```
ni       Xbar     n
10.000   2.182   12.000
```

If this is what you expect, then one way to do this would be as follows:

Step 1: Create Vectors

Step 2: Create Data frame from the above vectors

Step 3: Run your operations in a loop & fill in row by row.

```
nsim=50
n=seq.int(5, 5000, length.out=nsim)
ni<-vector(mode='numeric',length=nsim)
Xbar<-vector(mode='numeric',length=nsim)
out<-data.frame(ni=ni,Xbar=Xbar,n=n)

for ( i in 1:length(n)){
  X<- sample(seq(-n[i], n[i], length=n[i]+1), replace=T)
  out[i,'Xbar'] <- round(mean(X), 3)
  out[i,'ni']<-n[i]
}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]