# Create empty data frame with 200 rows and no columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is how I can do that:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:200)
df$a <- NULL
df
```

Result:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 200 rows
```

Can the same be achieved with only one command?

Comment: I guess the first question that comes to mind is _"Why?"_. Spidey-sense says you're going to use a `for` loop to try to fill this and there is probably a better way if you post what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917545/r-define-dimensions-of-empty-data-frame) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, Nah, that was just curiosity. I know what you are thinking, and yes, I do combine lapply with Reduce for the same effect.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can work (if the call to 2 functions is not considered 2 commands):

```
data.frame(matrix(, nrow=200, ncol=0))
#data frame with 0 columns and 200 rows
```

---

**Edit:** Another option is `data.frame()[1:200, ]`:

```
data.frame()[1:200, ]
# data frame with 0 columns and 200 rows
```

Comment: R says "missing agument" in `matrix`

Comment: @SashkoLykhenko which version of `R` ? (it works as expected with R 3.3.0)

Comment: data.frame(matrix(nrow=200, ncol=0)) this works as well

Comment: @Cath data.frame()[1:10, ] creates an empty data frame but while using a loop to fill values in this, we get weird row names.
 
df = data.frame()[1:10, ]
 
for (i in 1:10){
  x = i+2
  y = i+20
  df$x = x
  df$y = y
}

df

Comment: @DrNishaArora when creating the empty data.frame, `row.names` are set to `NA` followed by indices to avoid duplicated row.names. (This said, I doubt your loop will give you the output you're looking for)

Comment: @Cath Yup, so either we reset rownames later or we start with a non-empty data frame (with one row) & delete the first row later. Thanks

Comment: @DrNishaArora note that if you already know what you want to put in the data.frame, there is no need to create an empty one

Answer (score 13):

What about this?

```
data.frame(row.names = 1:200)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I discovered via `dput`:

```
structure(
   list(), 
   .Names = character(0), 
   row.names = c(NA, -200L), 
   class = "data.frame"
 )
```

Comment: That `row.names` trick might only work with recent R and the new ALTREP work